# Backtracking (recursividad) de optimización del mínimo coste en C

Tags: c, recursión, optimización

Por favor :), a ver si podéis echarme una manilla sobre cómo abordar la condición que me queda en este problema de optimización, en el que se pretende crear un andamio con hasta 5 piezas y minimizando su coste:

No logro almacenar en el array con 0 y 1 (andamio[]) la solución correcta de mínimo coste (*costeAndamio < coste_total).

He probado con: min 7m, max 8m, y <=25 y me devuelve las piezas 1 y 2, en lugar de la 4, que sería la más barata.

Aquí parte del código:

```
void insertarPiezas(Pieza piezas[]) 
{
    piezas[0].altura = 5;
    piezas[0].peso = 10;
    piezas[0].coste = 50;

    piezas[1].altura = 3;
    piezas[1].peso = 13;
    piezas[1].coste = 70;

    piezas[2].altura = 4;
    piezas[2].peso = 28;
    piezas[2].coste = 80;

    piezas[3].altura = 7;
    piezas[3].peso = 25;
    piezas[3].coste = 100;

    piezas[4].altura = 6;
    piezas[4].peso = 30;
    piezas[4].coste = 90;

}

void actualizarSolucion(int solucion_parcial[], Pieza piezas[], int andamio[],int *alturaAndamio, int *pesoAndamio, int *costeAndamio, int alturaMin)
{
    int altura_total = 0, peso_total = 0, coste_total = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_PIEZAS; i++)
    {
        if(solucion_parcial[i] == 1){
            altura_total += piezas[i].altura;
            peso_total += piezas[i].peso;
            coste_total += piezas[i].coste;
        }
    }

    if(alturaMin <= altura_total && *costeAndamio <= coste_total){ // ESTA ES LA PARTE QUE ME INTERESA Y NO FUNCIONA
        printf("\nCoste andamio = %d vs Coste total = %d", *costeAndamio, coste_total);

        minimoCoste(solucion_parcial, andamio, altura_total, peso_total, coste_total, *alturaAndamio, *pesoAndamio, *costeAndamio);

        *alturaAndamio = altura_total;
        *pesoAndamio = peso_total;
        *costeAndamio = coste_total;
    }
}

int minimoCoste(int solucion_parcial[], int andamio[], int altura_total, int peso_total, int coste_total, int *alturaAndamio, int *pesoAndamio, int *costeAndamio)
{

        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_PIEZAS; i++)
        {
            andamio[i] = solucion_parcial[i];
            printf("\n %d ",andamio[i]);
        }
    return andamio;
}
```